# Jinja2 templates rendering with blanks instead of variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, jinja2

I'm using jinja2 to generate basic python code for an "app generator" for the framework I'm building.

When rendered and written to a file, jinja2's output contains blanks where the variables ought to be.

I am building a dict of values from a YAML config file

app.pytemplate:

```
__author__ = {{authorname}}
from plugins.apps.iappplugin import IAppPlugin

class {{appname}}(IAppPlugin):
    pass
```

YAML:

```
#basic configuration
appname:  newApp
version:  0.1
repo_url: ''
#author configuration
authorname: 'Foo Bar'
authoremail: ''
```

generating code (i've snipped some stupid boilerplate arg parsing here)

```
# read in the YAML, if present.
with open(yamlPath) as _:
configDict = yaml.load(_)

# Make a folder whose name is the app.
appBasePath = path.join(args.output, configDict['appname'])
os.mkdir(appBasePath)

# render the templated app files
env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader(templatePath))
for file in os.listdir(templatePath):
    #render it
    template = env.get_template(file)
    retval = template.render(config=configDict)

    if file.endswith(".pytemplate"):
        if file == "app.pytemplate":
            # if the template is the base app, name the new file the name of the new app
            outfile = configDict['appname'] + ".py"
        else:
            #otherwise name it the same as its template with the right extension
            outfile = path.splitext(file)[0] + ".py"
        with open(path.join(appBasePath,outfile),"w") as _:
            _.write(retval)
```

the YAML is getting parsed correctly (`outfile` is getting set correctly), but the output is :

```
__author__ = 
from plugins.apps.iappplugin import IAppPlugin


class (IAppPlugin):
    pass
```

What stupid thing am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the yaml module returns a dictionary. there are 2 ways to solve this:

either you keep your template but change the way you pass your dictionary to the render method:

```
from jinja2 import Template

tmplt = Template('''
__author__ = {{authorname}}
class {{appname}}(IAppPlugin):
''')

yaml_dict = {'authorname': 'The Author',
             'appname': 'TheApp'}

print(tmplt.render(**yaml_dict))
```

or you pass the dictionary as is to render and change the template:

```
tmplt = Template('''
__author__ = {{yaml['authorname']}}
class {{yaml['appname']}}(IAppPlugin):
''')

yaml_dict = {'authorname': 'The Author',
             'appname': 'TheApp'}

print(tmplt.render(yaml=yaml_dict))
```

your jinja2 template accesses the arguments with keywords (as it should). if you just pass the dictionary to the render function you are providing no such keywords.

Comment: that was it. Changing the template seemed cleaner, so i went that way. Thanks.